# Is it require to install all API from 4.1 to 5.1 for target 4.1 while developing android application?

Tags: android

I want to make application which targets all the device which supports 4.1 and above Operating System.

**Is it necessary to install all sdk tools of *15* to *22 API*?**

*please suggest the answer*

Answer (score 1):

You need to install only `TargetSDK` version.

`minSDKVersion 14`

`targetSDKVersion 21`

`maxSDKVersion 22`

So you need the *API 21* installed only.

Comment: by doing this it will supourt jellybean ..?m worry about is it compatible to jellybean ?

Comment: Yes it will be Compatible with jellybean.